# How I display wagtail blog post in other pages like homepage

Tags: django, django-templates, wagtail

Noob here. So as the title I'm trying to display blog around my pages. What I'm trying to achive is:

- homepage who has a list of the latest post.
- Blog index Page.
- Blog category pages.
- a sidebar to use in my other pages.

So that's has been my step so far:

- set up a wagtail project;
- install wagtail-blog;
- moved blog folder to Lib in my root folder
- set up root, template, and staticfolder.

As I know by now my blog will show up only in my blog_index_page.html as a http:127.0.0.1/blog/ and blogpost  showing up in 127.0.0.1/blog/blog-post-name. So blog looks like working fine.

I'm really struggling to unbderstand how to implement the latest post in my homepage; making a category blog page and the sidebar who display latestpost around my site.

so that's my code:

blog/models.py

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger

from django.conf import settings

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from django.db.models import Count

from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from wagtail.snippets.models import register_snippet
from taggit.models import Tag
from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.core.fields import RichTextField
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel

from .abstract import (
    BlogCategoryAbstract,
    BlogCategoryBlogPageAbstract,
    BlogIndexPageAbstract,
    BlogPageAbstract,
    BlogPageTagAbstract
)


COMMENTS_APP = getattr(settings, 'COMMENTS_APP', None)


class BlogIndexPage(BlogIndexPageAbstract):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Blog index')

    @property
    def blogs(self):
        # Get list of blog pages that are descendants of this page
        blogs = BlogPage.objects.descendant_of(self).live()
        blogs = blogs.order_by(
            '-date'
        ).select_related('owner').prefetch_related(
            'tagged_items__tag',
            'categories',
            'categories__category',
        )
        return blogs

    def get_context(self, request, tag=None, category=None, author=None, *args,
                    **kwargs):
        context = super(BlogIndexPage, self).get_context(
            request, *args, **kwargs)
        blogs = self.blogs

        if tag is None:
            tag = request.GET.get('tag')
        if tag:
            blogs = blogs.filter(tags__slug=tag)
        if category is None:  # Not coming from category_view in views.py
            if request.GET.get('category'):
                category = get_object_or_404(
                    BlogCategory, slug=request.GET.get('category'))
        if category:
            if not request.GET.get('category'):
                category = get_object_or_404(BlogCategory, slug=category)
            blogs = blogs.filter(categories__category__name=category)
        if author:
            if isinstance(author, str) and not author.isdigit():
                blogs = blogs.filter(author__username=author)
            else:
                blogs = blogs.filter(author_id=author)

        # Pagination
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        page_size = 10
        if hasattr(settings, 'BLOG_PAGINATION_PER_PAGE'):
            page_size = settings.BLOG_PAGINATION_PER_PAGE

        paginator = None
        if page_size is not None:
            paginator = Paginator(blogs, page_size)  # Show 10 blogs per page
            try:
                blogs = paginator.page(page)
            except PageNotAnInteger:
                blogs = paginator.page(1)
            except EmptyPage:
                blogs = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        context['blogs'] = blogs
        context['category'] = category
        context['tag'] = tag
        context['author'] = author
        context['COMMENTS_APP'] = COMMENTS_APP
        context['paginator'] = paginator
        context = get_blog_context(context)

        return context

    subpage_types = ['blog.BlogPage']


@register_snippet
class BlogCategory(BlogCategoryAbstract):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
        verbose_name = _("Blog Category")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Blog Categories")


class BlogCategoryBlogPage(BlogCategoryBlogPageAbstract):
    class Meta:
        pass


class BlogPageTag(BlogPageTagAbstract):
    class Meta:
        pass


@register_snippet
class BlogTag(Tag):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True


def get_blog_context(context):
    """ Get context data useful on all blog related pages """
    context['authors'] = get_user_model().objects.filter(
        owned_pages__live=True,
        owned_pages__content_type__model='blogpage'
    ).annotate(Count('owned_pages')).order_by('-owned_pages__count')
    context['all_categories'] = BlogCategory.objects.all()
    context['root_categories'] = BlogCategory.objects.filter(
        parent=None,
    ).prefetch_related(
        'children',
    ).annotate(
        blog_count=Count('blogpage'),
    )
    return context


class BlogPage(BlogPageAbstract):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Blog page')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Blog pages')

    def get_blog_index(self):
        # Find closest ancestor which is a blog index
        return self.get_ancestors().type(BlogIndexPage).last()

    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
        context['blogs'] = self.get_blog_index().blogindexpage.blogs
        context = get_blog_context(context)
        context['COMMENTS_APP'] = COMMENTS_APP
        return context

    parent_page_types = ['blog.BlogIndexPage']
'''


blog/models.py

from django.db import models

from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.core.fields import RichTextField
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel




class HomePage(Page):
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('body', classname="full"),
    ]


def get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)

        # Add extra variables and return the updated context
        # note: be sure to get the `live` pages so you do not show draft pages
        context['blog_pages'] = BlogPage.objects.child_of(self).live()
        return context

class AboutMe(Page):
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)

    template = 'blog/blog_index_page.html'

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('body', classname="full"),

that's the for loop I'm trying to display the latest post


             {% block content %}
              <section id="section-personal-blog" data-bgcolor="#f5f5f5">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 text-center">
                            <h2>Latest Post</h2>
                            <div class="small-border"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div id="blog-carousel" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
                                <div class="bloglist item">
                                    <div class="post-content">
                                        <div class="post-image">
                                            <img src="{% static 'images/blog-2/pic-blog-1.jpg' %}" alt="" />
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="post-text">
                                        {% include blog/blog_post.html' with blog=self %}
                                        </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </section>
            {% endblock content %}
```

Thanks in advice for your time reading this and help me!